# How to get one string from a list of strings

Tags: c

Given a list of strings, I'm wondering how I can create a new string only containing one of the list of strings.

For example:

```
char* myStrings[]={"Frosty the Snowman", "Rudolph the red nosed reindeer"};
char oneString[]=myStrings[0];

printf("A string: %s\n", oneString);
```

In order to only print:

```
A string: Frosty the Snowman
```

It does not work because of an invalid initializer.

Sorry if this has been posted before, I could not find it. Thank you.

Edit - I know I can print it by doing myString[0] instead of oneString, but I am trying to create a new string with only one of the given strings.

Comment: Your array indexes are `zero` based, so as above `myStrings[0] = "Frosty the Snowman"`, `myStrings[1] = "Rudolph the red nosed reindeer"`, etc.. so `printf("A string: %s\n", myStrings[0]);` prints `"Frosty the Snowman"`

Comment: Use `strcpy`, C arrays are not assignable.

Comment: In C you cant initialize a variable dynamically (ie initialize a variable with another variable). So you need to create oneString first, THEN copy myStrings[0] into it.

Comment: Be careful `char *oneString=myStrings[0];` **is perfectly legal**. It assigns the address of `myStrings[0]` to the character pointer `oneString`

Comment: @Loocid: That's a new one. `int a = 0; int b = a;` Works, just not outside functions.

Comment: In C, this is called an array. Not a list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* myStrings[]={"Frosty the Snowman", "Rudolph the red nosed reindeer"};
    char oneString[500];
    strcpy(oneString,myStrings[0]);
    printf("A string: %s\n", oneString);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of a `character pointer` is fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* myStrings[]={"Frosty the Snowman", "Rudolph the red nosed reindeer"};
    char *oneString = myStrings[0];
    printf("A string: %s\n", oneString);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/prnpointer
A string: Frosty the Snowman
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
char oneString[]=myStrings[0];
```

to

```
char *oneString = myString[0];
```

and it will work!